# How to fix start up error using Lenovo Z580?

Tags: 64-bit, startup, lenovo

Laptop Lenovo Z580 with 8 RAM and Intel® Core™ i5-3210M, with Ubuntu 64 bits

The system hangs at start up stage, but sometimes loads after 3 or 4 times.

How to fix this trouble?

[image: boot showing list of USB devices]
[image: hang showing call trace]

Comment: What is the last message that you see? Does this freeze in a specific output?

Answer (score 0):

I found your problem in Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seabios/+bug/931371

And is a Duplicated of this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libguestfs/+bug/930634

The solution that they give is to update the `seabios` package in `precise-proposed`.